# Decomposition of vector space by operator in infinite dimensional case

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A: V \to W$ be a linear operator between vector spaces $V,W$.

Then, if  $V,W$ have finite dimensions, then there is a decomposition of $V$ by kernel of $A$ and image of    the transposed map of $A$, i.e., $V= \ker A +  A^T(W)$.

Is this decomposition also true in infinite dimensional cases?

---

Edit for comments

Let  $V,W$ be Hilbert spaces and bounded linear map $A:V \to W$, and the sets of all bounded linear operators $V^*,W^*$ and transposed map $A^T: W^* \to V^*$ which maps each $w^* \in W^*$ to $w^* \circ A \ \in V^*$. Using Riesz representation theorem, there is an isomorphism  $\# :V^* \to V$.

Then the analogy can be written by

$V= \ker A + \# \circ A^T(W^*)$.

Is this decomposition true?

Comment: What's the definition of "the transposed map"?

Comment: For $V,W$ Hilbert spaces and $A$ a continuous linear operator, it becomes $V=\ker A+\overline{A^*W}$.

Comment: Thorgott is right. For arbitrary $V, W, A$, finite dimensional or not, there is no such thing as the "transpose". You need $V, W$ to be inner product spaces to define it.